# Compare value between 2 datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 2 datagridviews. `dataGridView1` has 3 rows and `dataGridView2` has 2 rows.How to compare the values between them.

```
Exa: Datagridview1          Datagridview2    
Id name                     Id name
1  A                        3   C
2  B                        4   A
3  C
```

I want to compare:

> 1 vs 3, 1 vs 4,
>  
>   2 vs 3, 2 vs 4, 
>   3 vs 3, 3 vs 4.

I use the code below but it works incorrect.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.RowCount; j++)
    {   
        i++;
        string grid2 = dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string grid1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        if (grid1 == grid2 || dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() )
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing your increment statement (i++;) in the inner loop. You're incrementing your variable i twice.

Comment: yah, if i remove it, it's doesn't work(it only display value when i =0 and stop).

Comment: " only display value" where do you display a value? aren't you removing values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)**

If you want to iterate through a collection using a for loop it is not wise to increment the indexing variable additionally in the code with this line:

```
i++;
```

it is already incremented. So when you run through the `dataGridView2` you actually slide one position further also in `dataGridView1`. This is not what you want (as I see from your post where you describe the desired comparisons). You need to remove this line

**2)**

> I want to compare: 1 vs 3, 1 vs 4, 2 vs 3, 2 vs 4, 3 vs 3, 3 vs 4.

if you want to compare only the `name` column then your indexing is right :

```
dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[1]
```

but if you want to compare the Id column then it is wrong because indexing starts with `0`. So to get the correct value from the `Id` column you have to use it like this:

```
string grid2 = dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

With this comparison in your if-condition:

```
 dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString()
```

you additionally compare `A` with `C`. I don't see any reason for this (taken your description about the comparison desire). You can get rid of it.

**3)**

If you want to change the size of a collection (by deleting elements) through which you iterate it is wise to use a reversed for-loop which starts from the `dataGridView2.RowCount-1` and runs until `>= 0`. Otherwise you risk to run into an `ArgumentOutOfBounds` exception because you don't have as much elements after removal as you did when you started the loop. The element at the end index will not exist anymore.

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.RowCount; j++)
    {   
        string grid2 = dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string grid1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        if (grid1 == grid2)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The `dataGridView1` might display an additional empty row which is also counted in `dataGridView1.RowCount` in this case you need to start from `i = dataGridView1.RowCount-2`. Also after you have found a match and removed the row from `dataGridView1` it does not make sense to search further for matches for this row, since it is gone. So you should break out of the inner loop and proceed with the next line:

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.RowCount -1; j++)
    {
        string grid2 = dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string grid1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        if (grid1 == grid2)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index with your code :( i try to anyway but it doesn't work.I don't know where error code or visual?Last week, i use this code and it work successful.

Comment: @KateMid I made an edit to accomodate for this. Have a look

Comment: @KateMid you are welcome. Did you want to compare the `Id` or the `name` ?

Comment: Sr Mong Zhu. Here, i only example.Ij the real, I compare more than column@@

Comment: @KateMid ah ok, than happy to be of help :)